# PHP, using $_FILES and $_POST at the same time but its not working

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I am making a admin page to insert all attribute in MySQL and image upload in one folder but getting some error ,Here is code of form

```
<form role="form" id="form1" action="" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title:</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="enter title" class="form-control"required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">  
                <label>Image:</label>
                <input type="file" name="upload" id="postimage" class="form-control"> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="reset" name="reset" value="reset">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Content:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content" placeholder="explain in brief">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Age:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter require age" name="age">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="submitpost" value="Submit-Post" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and when i am using PHP code for inserting my image in one folder name img and other attributes in MySQL table.

```
<?php
    $target_dir = "../../img/";
    if (isset($_FILES['upload'])and isset($_POST['submitpost'])) {   
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
            if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
                $title=$_POST['title'];
                $age=$_POST['age'];
                $content=$_POST['content'];
                $query="INSERT INTO `posts`
                            (`id`,`title`, `image`,`age`, `content`) 
                    VALUES (null,'$title','$target_file','$age','$content')"; 
                if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('passed')</script>";
                }else{
                    echo "<script>alert('not passed')</script>";
                }
            }else{
                echo "<script>alert('problem with image upload')</script>";}
        }
    ?>
```

But after submitting i am getting nothing, neither error or any notice nothing ,i don't know what is problem help me and I did try some other code then its inserting in table but image does not uploading in target folder .Help me through it i am new in PHP , so

Comment: **DEBUGGING** Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: use `$target_dir = "../img";` instead of `$target_dir = "../../img/";` it is the correct path which uploaded the file to img folder

Comment: your form has to be like `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: try print_r($_POST) check if form posting any values

Comment: @AkshayParate i did try `$target_dir = "../img";` but when debugging for target  image using `file_exists`  its not founding and when i did try my code it is finding target image.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in the form for file input, its wrong. add like below

```
<form role="form" id="form1" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Add **PHP** code like

```
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/img/';
if(!empty($_FILES['upload']['name'] && isset($_POST['submitpost']))){
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)){
        extract($_POST);
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$title);
        $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$age);
        $content = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$content);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`,`title`,`image`,`age`,`content`) 
            VALUES (null,'{$title}','{$target_file}','{$age}','{$content}');";
        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
            echo "<script>alert('passed')</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('not passed')</script>";
        }   
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('problem with image upload')</script>";
    }
}
```

please make sure `$target_dir` is correct path of your image upload directory.